# Objective C - divide long by a float without losing precision

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, precision, long-integer, divide

I'm having precision problems when dividing an long type with a float and ended up messing the calculations in the app. Let say I'm just converting a millisecond to second, since that is a requirement on our end. Below is a sample test case

```
long startTimeMS = 2529095;
NSTimeInterval expectedStartTime = 2529.095
NSTimeInterval startTime = startTimeMS / 1000.f; //Results to "2529.09497"
double startTimeDouble = startTimeMS / 1000.0 // Results to "2529.0949999999998"

XTCAssert(startTime == expectedStartTime, @"Invalid start time")
```

Upon dividing a long by float, it loses precision by a 3 thousandth. Similar with long divided by double.

How do I make it so that dividing it would come out the same as the expected start time? I'm guessing rounding up to nearest thousandth in decimal would also be good but the rounding methods I found here isn't reliable either like this

```
float roundToTwo(float num)
{
    return round(100 * num) / 100;
}
```

Which most likely return the same value

Comment: Are you sure about your example? `2529095 / 100.f` resulting in `2595.09497` seems like a huge error.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want the times to use floats rather than integers? (you could convert the times to doubles for display purposes later).

Comment: @MarkDickinson I pondered answering that in the first computation, the `long` to `float` conversion lost precision, but that doesn't explain the second result.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Exactly, and the comment says “Results to "2595.0949999999998"”

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Ah, sorry; I see. Apologies for being an idiot. Surely a typo in the original post?

Comment: @PascalCuoq To further explain this, we're dealing with ad cue points for a  video content and we have two sources for getting the said cuepoints. One from the discovery API on our end, which returns milliseconds, while the other is from a 3rd party like Freewheel, which returns seconds. Let say both return 2529095 ms and 2529.095 s for a cue point respectively. Both has to match on the device to be able to play the cue point for the ads but due to the said miscalculation, its not able to play it

Comment: Note that doing this approach would still return the same value. `[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.03f", self.adStartTime] floatValue]`

Comment: @PaoloPascua: It looks as though you have a typo in your numbers, though: your `startTimeMS` starts with the digits *2529*, while the numbers in the comments start with the digits *2595*. It's very unlikely that loss of precision is causing the difference. Please can you double check the values, and update the post if necessary.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks for pointing that out, though I'm more concerned with the decimal numbers rather than the whole numbers

Comment: I strongly suspect that `startTimeDouble` is already exactly equal to your `expectedStartTime`. What does the assert show if you replace `startTime` with `startTimeDouble`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how floating-point works. The floating-point types `float` and `double` are *binary* types.

Your decimal fraction `0.095` is equal to `9/100 + 5/1000` - all decimal fractions are sums of `1/(10^n)` fractions.

Now consider ordinary fractions, what is the decimal fraction equivalent of `1/3`? It's `3/10 + 3/100 + 3/1000 + ...` or equivalently `0.333...`, there is *no exact* way to represent it as the same of decimal fractions.

For the types `float` and `double` the fractional part are sums of `1/(2^n)` fractions. Similarly to the above not all decimal fractions can be precisely written as binary fractions.

In addition to the differences induced by using different bases, decimal vs. binary, computer floating-point is limited in the number of digits in any number while real math is unlimited, and thus computations may not produce *exact* results.

For the above reasons it is good floating-point practice to never test for exact equality but rather whether the difference of two numbers is less than a small value (which may vary depending on the magnitude of the numbers). In your case you might decide that two numbers are "equal" if their difference is less than, say, 0.1ms.

Now having said all that in the particular example you give, if it is corrected, the numbers are actually the same, but neither is `2529.095`:

```
long startTimeMS = 2529095;
NSTimeInterval expectedStartTime = 2529.095;     // Result is approx "2529.0949999999998"
NSTimeInterval startTime = startTimeMS / 1000.0; // Result is approx "2529.0949999999998"
```

These two numbers will compare equal, but this need not be the case for all values. It would be better to write your assert as:

```
XTCAssert(fabs(startTime - expectedStartTime) <= 0.0001, @"Invalid start time");
```

where `0.0001` should be whatever fraction of a second is small enough that you deem the two values "equal".

You really should read up on floating-point arithmetic if you are going to be doing work which requires precision, as you do more operations the differences due to base and limited digits accumulate and there are techniques to minimise and deal with these.

HTH

Comment: Giving this as the correct answer for the use of the double and the epsilon case, since this is the closest answer that I can take

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a float for this operation - as base 10 representation of decimals in floats always produce uneven numbers. A better solution is to use fixed point arithmetic and multiply everything by 1000 (or more if you require more decimal precision). This avoids the rounding errors intrinsic in floating point calculations.

See:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors

For a better answer on what causes these errors.

Comment: I'm dealing with NSTimeInterval, which is of type double. I need it to convert it to double/float to include the millisecond info in it

Comment: Do the math as fixed point (integer) math and then convert to double at the end. This will avoid the accumulation of rounding errors that working with floats will give.